# Can't use fopen, fclose, and ifstream

Tags: smart-contract, compilation, stream

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the problem. This happened when I use eosiocpp to compile my .cpp file into .wast. Does the compiler not allow file reading?

Answer (score 1):

The EOS smart contracts do not have file system. Thus, you cannot use file system functions.

Practical thinking for the homework:

- Where would the file reside as the code is executed on a block producer? The block producers cannot access your hard disk.

Comment: Perhaps a different question: What tooling is available to understand the program flow in contracts and debug them?

Comment: Please use Ask Question button to ask a question, so it is properly discussed.